# jQuery localStorage and arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

What I am trying to do is store some data from input forms into an array, but is there any way to create the array if it does not exist then run the rest of the script, otherwise, if it does exist then continue with the same script as well.

I want to store the array as localStorage, so later on I can display the items.

```
var routes = [];

div.on('click', function() {
   routes.push({ routeF : $('input[name=routeFrom]').val() });
   routes.push({ routeT : $('input[name=routeTo]').val() });
   routes.push({ leaving : $('select').val() });

   localStorage['routes'] = JSON.stringify(routes);
   var storedRoutes = JSON.parse(localStorage['routes']);
});
```

I want to be able to do this without doing:

```
if(routes[]) {
    //do code
} else { 
    var routes = []; 
    //do same code
}
```

Comment: if you need to do something in your code based on wether something is X or Y, you need an if-statement. In OOP you can abstract this to a point where you simply call a method (which does that for you), but that's not the case here. What is wrong with you if-else-statement?

Comment: I just didn't want to repeat the same instructions for both conditions

Comment: So why not move the `same code` from the body of `if` and `else` to after the conditional? The effect will be the same. If the array is truthy then nothing will happen, else it will create the array. Either way, your remaining code gets an array instance.

Comment: Also, the condition of the `if` ought to be `if (routes)` and not `if (routes[])`

Comment: When I put it outside, it gives 'Cannot call method 'push' of undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the routes variable already declared?

If so, you should be able to do something like this:

```
div.on('click', function() {
  // The following line will set routes to an empty array if set.
  // Be careful here, as if you have not declared routes as a variable,
  // it will become a global variable.
  (!routes || !routes.length) && (routes = []);
  // End Change ...
  routes.push({ routeF : $('input[name=routeFrom]').val() });
  routes.push({ routeT : $('input[name=routeTo]').val() });
  routes.push({ leaving : $('select').val() });

  localStorage['routes'] = JSON.stringify(routes);
  var storedRoutes = JSON.parse(localStorage['routes']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the code behind the if-statement:

```
if(routes) {
    // do nothing
} else { 
    var routes = []; 
}
// do the code for both cases
```

Or, without the "nothing":

```
if( ! routes) {
    var routes = []; 
}
// do the code
```